# How to make a multiple line text box fill parent div

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a MVC 3 project and CSS has never been my strong point but I have a page laded out with five div's positioned: container, top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right.

Within the bottom right div it's child is a multiple line text box that I need to fill the parent div adding padding on the right and bottom. #div-notes is assigned to the id property for the text box I need to stretch, and the parent div is #div-container-optional2.

Can someone help me understand why I can't fill this div with a text box?

```
 #div-container {
     width: fill-available;
     margin: 0 auto;

 }
 #div-content1
 {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
 }
 #div-content2
 {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
 }
 #div-container-optional1
 {
     clear: both;
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
 }
 #div-container-optional2
 {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
     margin-top: 38px;
 }
 #div-submit-button
 {
     clear: both;
     float: left;
     margin-top: 5px;  
 }
 #div-notes {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     position: relative;
 }
```

Code form the view:

```
<div id="div-container-optional2">
  <hr />
  <div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)
  </div>
  <div id="div-notes" class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes)
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div-submit-button">
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what you're asking, but to make the textarea fill up the parent container, you can set its width and height to 100%.

```
<div id="parent">
    <textarea rows="2" cols="20">blah</textarea>    
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

#parent {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#parent textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KE5ew/)

Comment: I should have mentioned that no matter what value I set the width or height (px or %) the text box stays the same size. I tried setting both to 100% with no joy.

Comment: Can you isolate and post just the HTML (view source in browser) and CSS for the part your having issues with? I'm not familiar with asp.net so I can't use your provided HTML since it's not real HTML. If isolating it doesn't give you the same problem also let me know. Put something on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that we can work with.

Comment: I saved a .html file with the CSS file on jsfiddle but it did not ask for a file name during the save process.

Comment: Thanks for your help and when I looked back at your example I noticed your #parent textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; which I translated to #div-notes textarea 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 281px;
}.... Thanks!
}

Comment: Well, glad I could help! For the future, when you click Save on a jsfiddle page, the URL changes to something like `http://jsfiddle.net/pVD7j/` the `pVD7j` is unique. So you click save and copy the new URL to share! When you modify an existing one, you click Update and it will make it like `http://jsfiddle.net/pVD7j/1/` for first revision or `/2/` for 2nd, etc.